# different aggregations within pd groupby in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this and need to perform multiple aggregations within groupby, including concatenating rows and different operations on the same cols

```
import pandas as pd
sample = pd.DataFrame({'group':['a']*3+['b']*6, 'time':[1,2,4,6,7,8,9,12,15],'type':['a','x','b','y','x','a','y','b','x']})
sample
```

this is what I tried and the result contains unwanted index and \n. is there a good way to not have those included?

```
sample.groupby('group').agg(ts = ('time',lambda x: ''.join(str(x))), 
                         type_max = ('type','max'), type_count = ('type','count'))
```

[image]

Comment: can you post an example of what you want the dataframe to look like after groupby aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert with `.astype(str)`:

```
sample.groupby('group').agg(ts = ('time',lambda x: ''.join(x.astype(str))), 
                            type_max = ('type','max'), 
                            type_count = ('type','count'))
```

Output:

```
             ts type_max  type_count
group                               
a           124        x           3
b      67891215        y           6
```

Comment: `str(x)` returns the string representation of the series, pretty much what you get with `print(x)`. So it would include index, value, `...`, etc...